# Why can the directional derivative be computed from the gradient?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Given a function $f$ from vectors to scalars, and a vector $\vec v$, the directional derivative of $f$ with respect to $\vec v$ is defined as $\nabla_{\vec v} f = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(\vec x + h \vec v) - f(\vec x)}{h}$. It can also be computed as $\nabla_{\vec v} f = \vec v \cdot \nabla f$. I find it very unintuitive that these two things are equivalent. I've looked at some proofs of this, but they seem to be using concepts that I don't yet understand.

For example, in two dimensions, if $\vec v = \pmatrix{1\\1}$, then the directional derivative is $\nabla_{\vec v} f = f_x + f_y$. Expanding the definitions, this gives
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h, y+h) - f(x,y)}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h, y) - f(x,y)}{h} + \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x, y+h) - f(x,y)}{h}$$

This seems to imply that, for small values of $h \neq 0$, we can make the approximation
$$\frac{f(x+h, y+h) - f(x,y)}{h} \approx \frac{f(x+h, y) - f(x,y)}{h} + \frac{f(x, y+h) - f(x,y)}{h}$$
which simplifies to $$f(x+h,y+h) \approx  f(x+h,y) + f(x,y+h) - f(x,y)$$

Why can we make this approximation? I can see that this approximation is exact when $f$ is a linear function. But for general $f$, why can we get any information for $f(\_,\_)$ from values of $f(x,\_)$ and $f(\_,y)$? Knowing the values of $f$ for some inputs give us no information for the values of $f$ for other inputs, right?

Comment: That's not the directional derivative of $v$. See here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2869111/interpretation-of-directional-derivative-without-unit-vector

Comment: @AndrewZhang Edited the question to clarify. My issue is that there are two formulas for the directional derivative, and I don't understand why these two things are equivalent.

Comment: I meant that the directional derivative with respect to $v = (1,1)$ is not correct. It's correct if $v = 2^{-1/2}(1,1)$.

Comment: Different people use the term ‘directional derivative’ in different ways. I'm with @AndrewZhang in that I would only use it when you divide by the magnitude of the vector, and since you don't have any reason to do that in this question, that means that you'd want to use a different term here (such as ‘the derivative of $f$ along $\vec v$’). But if your textbook/class/professor uses ‘directional derivative’ for this, then it's hardly alone, and I can't really insist to that you have to use my terminology instead of your text's.

Comment: @AndrewZhang Wikipedia has two definitions for the directional derivative. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative#Definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that the approximation
$$ f ( x + h , y + h ) \approx f ( x + h , y ) + f ( x , y + h ) - f ( x , y ) $$
is not always valid.  On the other hand, if $ f $ is linear (even in the affine sense, that is of the form $ f ( x , y ) = a x + b y + c $ but not necessarily $ f ( x , y ) = a x + b y $), then the approximation is not only valid but exact.  Indeed, in that case we even have the more general version
$$ f ( x + h , y + k ) \approx f ( x + h , y ) + f ( x , y + k ) - f ( x , y ) $$
(where some of the $ h $s are now $ k $s, so I'm no longer necessarily using your particular vector $ \vec v $).

In general, this approximation is valid whenever $ f $ is *approximately* linear, or more precisely whenever $ f $ has a good linear approximation near any point.  In other words, the approximation is valid when $ f $ is *differentiable*.  Since not every function is differentiable, this is not a trivial or automatic thing!  We have a lot of theorems showing that various functions are differentiable, but in general, you do have to check this.  And so this equivalence between the limit and the dot product is only true for differentiable functions.

Comment: So the "f is differentiable" part is not just boilerplate bookkeeping? I assumed that if f had a gradient, it had to be differentiable. Is that not true? Does "differentiable" not just mean "has a numerical value when differentiated"?

Comment: @TheemathasChirananthavat Differentiability is stronger than existence of partials. See here: https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_partials_implies_differentiable

Comment: @TheemathasChirananthavat For an illustrative example of the equivalence failing due to lack of differentiability even though the gradient exists, see [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2152084/26369) to [Is there always a direction in which the directional derivative of a function is zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2151825/26369).

Answer (score 1):

Take two distinct points $P_0$ and $P_1$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$.We'll assume that $f:B \to \mathbb R$ where $B$ is an open ball in $\mathbb{R^n}$ centred at $P_0$, that $f$ and all its partials are continuously differentiable in $B$ and that all the points we talk about are in $B$. In $\mathbb{R^2}$, we can write $P_0=(x_0,y_0),P_1=(x_1,y_1)$. Let $\mathbf v$ be the vector from $P_0$to $P_1$ so $\mathbf v=[x_1-x_0,y_1-y_0.]$ The line joining $P_0$ and $P_1$ has parametric equation $(x,y)= P_0+t\mathbf v$, i.e.$$x=x_0+t(x_1-x_0),y=y_0+t(y_1-y_0).$$ Let $g(t)=f(P_0+t \mathbf v)$ i.e.$$g(t)=f(x_0+t(x_1-x_0),y_0+t(y_1-y_0))$$ Then $g^{\prime}(t)$ is the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction $\mathbf v$ and the chain rule gives $$g^{\prime}(t)=f_1(x_0+t(x_1-x_0),y_0+t(y_1-y_0))(x_1-x_0)+f_2(x_0+t(x_1-x_0),y_0+t(y_1-y_0))(y_1-y_0)$$ i.e. $$g^{\prime}(t)=\mathbf v \bullet\nabla f(P_0+t\mathbf v)$$. Note that the mean-value theorem gives $$g(1)-g(0)=g^{\prime}(t) \text { for some } 0<t<1$$ i.e. $$f(P_1)-f(P_0)=\mathbf v \bullet \nabla f(P_*)$$ where $P_*$ is on the line joining the points $P_0$ and $P_1$ and between them.All the above works the same for any $\mathbf{R^n}$